# AWS s3 sync multiple folders to different destinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-s3

I'm trying to sync two different folders to separate destinations in the same s3 bucket, but I keep getting this error in Jenkins:

> The user-provided path folder2/ does not exist.
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

The strange this is that the `folder2` folder exists. My Jenkins shell command looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

# set some env vars

docker build --build-arg APP_ENV --build-arg DEPLOY_ROOT=${ACTUAL_COMMIT_HASH} -t docker-thing .
docker run --rm \
--env S3_BUCKET \
--env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
--env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
--env AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
docker-thing \

# sync folder 1
aws s3 sync folder1/ s3://${S3_BUCKET}/

# sync folder 2
aws s3 sync folder2/ s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${ACTUAL_COMMIT_HASH}/
```

Folder 1 will sync no problem, but then the second folder will not saying that it does not exist when in fact it does exist.

If I were to switch the order in which I sync these I will get the same results. Folder 2 would sync and Folder 1 would not.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The backslashes make it look like you're running the first command inside of docker and the second outside of docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to run docker twice.

```
docker run --rm \
--env S3_BUCKET \
--env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
--env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
--env AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
docker-thing \

# sync folder 1
aws s3 sync folder1/ s3://${S3_BUCKET}/

docker run --rm \
--env S3_BUCKET \
--env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
--env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
--env AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
docker-thing \

# sync folder 2
aws s3 sync folder2/ s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${ACTUAL_COMMIT_HASH}/
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash should be removed from this line:

```sh
docker-thing \
```